# Python boto3 - Athena Query - start_query_execution - The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

My code to get Athena Query is

```
    self.athenaDataSource = "AwsCatalog"
    self.athenaDB = "prod_myapp_app"
    self.athenaResultBucket = "s3://s3-athena-prod-results/"
```

and here i show I create client and call  .start_query_execution

```
    clientAthena = boto3.client('athena', region_name=awsRegion)
    athenaQueryExecResp = clientAthena.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=self.athenaQuery,
        QueryExecutionContext={ 'Database': self.athenaDB },
        ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': self.athenaResultBucket }
    )
    print("athenaQueryExecResp= "+str(athenaQueryExecResp))
```

I get this error

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

The thing is it means I am not passing security which si correct but how do I pass the credentials. I checked https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution it never mentions anythign about passing credentials security access and token

Comment: Are you running locally or in aws lambda?

Comment: The error message is suggesting that your credentials are stored with an Access Key, Secret Key and Security Token. This third entity is used when using _temporary credentials_, such as those returned by an `AssumeRole` command. If you are running this code on your own computer, check the contents of the `~/.aws/credentials` file to see whether a `aws_security_token` is defined. If it is, it has a bad value.

Comment: Interestingly, sounds very similar to: [Getting Error “The security token included in the request is invalid” UnrecognizedClientException when calling the StartQueryExecution operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63262311/174777)

Comment: Thanks that was my problem I have resolved it .

Comment: worked for me after setting "AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" env variable along with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY - thanks @JohnRotenstein