# Getting Error "The security token included in the request is invalid" UnrecognizedClientException when calling the StartQueryExecution operation

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, redash

I am getting error while setup data source connection in redash with athena credential.

I have a valid access in athena where i can run query and fetch logs from S3. Now i want to integrate athena with redash, SO i am getting error "An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: The security token included in the request is invalid."

Also please let me know if i am missing something here. i have full access in athena to my user.

Please find the attached image and help me out on this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gagn5.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q0hK.png)

Comment: Interestingly, sounds very similar to: [Python boto3 - Athena Query - start_query_execution - The security token included in the request is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63255603/174777)

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of reasons for that error message:

1. The credentials are invalid.
2. You are using credentials generated with STS `AssumeRole` or `GetSessionToken`, and you are not including the session token in the authentication parameters (most UIs won't give you the option to input a session token though).
3. Your IAM policy used requires an MFA token to be present, and you haven't provided one (I've never seen a UI that has an option for this).

I assume you've tested your credentials somehow and that the first reason can be ruled out.

I suspect that this UI does not work with anything but IAM user credentials – i.e. not temporary credentials, not role credentials, and nothing that has conditions for MFA, or IP ranges, or anything like that in the policy.

I suggest you start by using the same credentials to start a query execution with aws-cli. If you get the same error you know it's the IAM policy (or possibly that you're missing a session token), but if the API call succeeds, the issue is in how the UI does the API call.